# Spring integeration - error-channel  handling issues

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am new in Spring Integeration.I have one requirement Using spring integeration

1. read a txt file (from Source folder)
2. do some validation
3. if validation is  success -write into sucess file (in sucess folder)
4. If the validation is fail -write into failure file (in error folder)
5. if the file format is incorrect means I have to move that file into error folder(Ex excepted columns is 2 but in my file contain columns is 1)

My  config file  is like this

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:si="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
        xmlns:file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-1.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file-1.0.xsd">

        <bean id="checkCSVReader"
            class="com.check.wrapper">
            <property name="pzMapXML" value="classpath:sampleFileFormat.xml" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="checkTrasnFomer"
            class="com.check.checkTransfomer">
            <property name="wrapper" ref="checkCSVReader" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="fileErrorProcessor"
            class="com.check.ErrorChannelWriter">
        </bean>
        <bean id="listToStringTrans"
            class="com.check.ListToStringTransfomer"></bean>


    <bean id="validation"
            class="com.check.Validation"/>

        <file:inbound-channel-adapter directory="file://D:\check\soruce"   prevent-duplicates="false" 
            auto-create-directory="true" channel="readChannel" >
            <si:poller id="Poller">
                <si:interval-trigger interval="10000" />
            </si:poller>
        </file:inbound-channel-adapter>

        <si:channel id="readChannel" />

        <si:chain input-channel="readChannel" output-channel="processChannel">
            <si:header-enricher error-channel="errorFile" />
            <file:file-to-string-transformer />
            <si:transformer ref="checkTrasnFomer" method="transform" />
            <si:service-activator ref="validation"
                method="validate" />
        </si:chain>

        <si:channel id="processChannel" />

        <si:transformer ref="listToStringTrans" method="transformList"
            input-channel="processChannel" output-channel="finalOut" />

        <si:channel id="finalOut" />

        <file:outbound-channel-adapter id="checkSuccFileOutBound"
            auto-create-directory="true" delete-source-files="true"
            directory="file://D:\check\success" channel="finalOut">
        </file:outbound-channel-adapter>

        <si:channel id="errorFile" />

        <si:transformer ref="fileErrorProcessor"
            input-channel="errorFile" output-channel="errorChannel" method="transformError" />

        <file:outbound-channel-adapter id="errorChannel"
            directory="file://D:\check\error" delete-source-files="true"
             />

        <si:channel id="checkFileErr" />
    </beans>
```

my checkFlatPackCVSParserWrapper class is

```
    public class checkFlatPackCVSParserWrapper {
        private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog("checkFlatPackCVSParserWrapper");
        private Resource pzMapXML;
        private char delimiter = ',';
        private char qualifier = '"';
        private boolean ignoreFirstRecord = false;

        public Resource getPzMapXML() {
            return pzMapXML;
        }
        public void setPzMapXML(Resource pzMapXML) {
            this.pzMapXML = pzMapXML;
        }
        public char getDelimiter() {
            return delimiter;
        }
        public void setDelimiter(char delimiter) {
            this.delimiter = delimiter;
        }
        public char getQualifier() {
            return qualifier;
        }
        public void setQualifier(char qualifier) {
            this.qualifier = qualifier;
        }
        public boolean isIgnoreFirstRecord() {
            return ignoreFirstRecord;
        }
        public void setIgnoreFirstRecord(boolean ignoreFirstRecord) {
            this.ignoreFirstRecord = ignoreFirstRecord;
        }

        public Parser getParser(String csv) {
            if(LOG.isDebugEnabled())
                LOG.debug("getParser: " + csv);

            Parser result = null;
            try {
                result = DefaultParserFactory.getInstance().newDelimitedParser(
                        pzMapXML.getInputStream(), //xml column mapping
                        new ByteArrayInputStream(csv.getBytes()),  //txt file to parse
                        delimiter, //delimiter
                        qualifier, //text qualfier
                        ignoreFirstRecord);

            }catch (Exception e) {
                if(LOG.isDebugEnabled())
                   LOG.debug("Unable to read file:  " + e );
                throw new RuntimeException("File Parse exception");
            }   
            return result;
        }
    }
```

sampleFileFormat.xml is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE PZMAP SYSTEM  "flatpack.dtd" >
    <PZMAP>
        <COLUMN name="FIRSTNAME" />
        <COLUMN name="LASTNAME" />
    </PZMAP> 


 and checkTransfomer is 


    public class checkTransfomer {
        private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(checkTransfomer.class);
        private CheckFlatPackCVSParserWrapper wrapper;

        public String transform(String csv) {
            Parser parser = wrapper.getParser(csv);
            if(LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
                LOG.debug("Parser is: " + parser);
            }        
            DataSet ds = parser.parse();
            ArrayList<Check> list = new ArrayList<Check>();
            while(ds.next()) {
                Check check= new Check();
                check.setFirstName(ds.getString("FIRSTNAME"));
                check.setLastName(ds.getString("LASTNAME"));
                if(LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    LOG.debug("Bean value is: " + bean);
                }        
                list.add(bean);            
            }
            if(LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
                LOG.debug("Records fetched is: " + list.size());
            }        
            return list.toString();
        }

        public CheckFlatPackCVSParserWrapper getWrapper() {
            return wrapper;
        }

        public void setWrapper(CheckFlatPackCVSParserWrapper wrapper) {
            this.wrapper = wrapper;
        }
```

And my ErrorChannelWriter is

```
    public class ErrorChannelWriter {

        public static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(ErrorChannelWriter.class);

        public Message<?> transformError(ErrorMessage errorMessage) {
            if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
                LOG.debug("Transforming errorMessage is: " + errorMessage);
            }
            return ((MessagingException) errorMessage.getPayload())
                    .getFailedMessage();
        }
        }
```

and my validagtion class is

```
  com.check.Validation

  public class Validation 
  {

   void validation(CheckCheck)
   {
  if(Check.getFirstName().equals("maya"))
  {
  throw new RuntimeException("Name Already exist");
  }



  }

  }
```

and my ListToStringTransfomer is

```
      public class ListToStringTransfomer {
        private static final Log LOG=LogFactory.getLog(ListToStringTransfomer.class);


        public String transformList(List<IssueAppBean> list) {
            return list.toString();
        }

    }
```

and my file containing one  fields instead of two fields

```
> maya
```

here  my file format is wrong, so record is moving to error folder.but there is no error message. how can i add error message(TOO FEW COLUMNS WANTED: 2 GOT: 1) when my file format is incorrect.
my requirement is in my error  file should contaion

> maya -TOO FEW COLUMNS WANTED: 2 GOT: 1 or(Any error message )

please give me any solution

Comment: If your logging is configure and you can see results 'LOG.debug' then you can just use 'LOG.WARN'.But thats just loging depends where you want to see the error how do want to handle it.This bit is not a Spring issue you just have not added any error handling.

Comment: Hi Shahzeb ,really thanks for ur reply ,,how can i  error handling in ErrorChannelWriter class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you should go through the error channel to solve this requirement. The main reason for this is that invalid input in this case is an expected scenario. The errorChannel is the channel that Spring Integration sends messages to if an unexpected exception happens in an endpoint.

If you add some header to the message if a validation failed, you can route based on that header and also record the failure message there. You can then send your error message to a log file or whatever on your own.